Is there a way to calculate the osmotic pressure between two or even three solutions?
From what I've read about osmotic pressure, the "measurement" and "calculation" of osmotic pressure always applies to a system in which "pure water" and a solution is separated by a semipermeable membrane.

I can't find a way to measure or calculate the osmotic pressure is both sides are solutions.
And I also can't figure out if water contacts two solutions at the same time, will the osmotic pressure be independent of each other? ( What I mean is like the picture below, but with two cylinders in the water.

Is there any textbook that discuss these kind of situations?

Just take two solutions, for the measurement or calculation.  How exactly you could not find the way?

$\Pi=\Delta cRT$, for the net osmotic pressure at the membrane, where delta represents the difference in concentrations.

Oh, I wasn't sure I could just use the difference in the concentration.
What I read in books was "Π=cRT", so I thought it could only apply to solution-water.
Now I get it, thank you!

Can you recommend a textbook on osmotic pressure? Mine all give "Π=cRT" instead of Π=ΔcRT, maybe my books are only introductions. I want to read further in this topic, thank you.
